# How to switch (folium) off the layers when plotting the map

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using folium, I want to plot a map that does not start with the markers turned on, as it usually does. I want all the markers to be switched off at first. Then, I want to be able to switch them on one by one.

As an example, I have the following code:

```
map = folium.Map(location=[-14.235004, -51.92528],
                      zoom_start=4)

author1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='author1')
author2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='author2')

for i, v in res.iterrows():
    popup = """
    Author : <b>%s</b><br>
    """ % (v['author'])

    if v['autor'] == 'Rubens':
        folium.CircleMarker(location=[v['LATITUDE'], v['LONGITUDE']],
                            radius=4,
                            tooltip=popup,
                            color='blue',
                            fill_color='blue',
                            fill=True).add_to(author1)
    if v['autor'] == 'Roberts':
        folium.CircleMarker(location=[v['LATITUDE'], v['LONGITUDE']],
                            radius=4,
                            tooltip=popup,
                            color='blue',
                            fill_color='blue',
                            fill=True).add_to(author2)

author1.add_to(map)
author2.add_to(map)

folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(map)
```

This code works perfectly fine. But it plots my map with the layers turned on. At first, when I first see the map, I want them turned off. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Set show=False for the folium.Choropleth layer you want to remain hidden when you first see the map.